# Difference between NVIDIA drivers and CUDA?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I have a google cloud instance with tesla K80 GPU (ubuntu 16.04). Now I'm confused with DO I need to install NVIDIA drivers first or CUDA directly?

can anyone explain to me what exactly the difference between them?

Comment: Cuda will install drivers if they aren't already installed.